# Error in data filtration using listbox selection in excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox

I have combo list box through which I want to filter table starting from I6 to L21. Here is the snap of Listbox and Table.[image]
But when I select to one or multiple option and try to filter data from table it gives me "object required" error.
Here is my code

```
Sub cmd1_Click()
    Dim x As Variant
    ReDim x(0)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            x(UBound(x)) = ListBox1.List(i)
            ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Sheet2.Range("I6:L35").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=x, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: *Where* is the error?

Comment: For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

Comment: `Option Explicit` is missing, and `ListBox1` is undefined.

Comment: Also consider sizing your array with `ReDim x(0 To {ListBox1}.ListCount - 1)` instead of copying it all over at every iteration every time just to add one more item (after figuring out what `ListBox1` is actually called - note that nobody here can know this. If the listbox has no items, you will want to bail out (`Exit Sub`) immediately.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon listbox is there in snap you see.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox1` doesn't exist in that scope. Either it's not called that, or it's otherwise not in scope. Verify the name, fix accordingly.

But the code shouldn't even have been allowed to *compile* with undefined identifiers in the first place. Always put `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.

You can tick the "require variable declaration" checkbox in the VBE options dialog to have `Option Explicit` automatically added to every module.

Comment: the name is Listbox1, i have added properties snap shot.

Comment: @UmarFarooq is it an ActiveX control? It has to be an ActiveX control. You can't access form controls with an identifier like that.

Comment: None. The problem is the listbox. If you double-click the listbox, does it create a `Private Sub ListBox1_Something` **in that same module you have your procedure in**? The `ListBox1` identifier is only in-scope in the worksheet module it exists in.

Comment: I have selected listbox in design mode and press view code a new module Sub ListBox15_Change() appears

Comment: @UmarFarooq looks like the name is `ListBox15`, not `Listbox1` then.... The new procedure can't possibly be in a new (standard?) module if the actual control is on a worksheet, that makes no sense.